# Element Wise Division in Pandas not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, having 2 columns.

```
col1
>>> 0    6.382474405435247e+08
1    2.414721440547710e+11
2    1.078680797585678e+13
3    5.234307123383891e+14
4    2.819640463840954e+16
5    1.723860035624660e+18
6    1.221906929903091e+20
7    1.024971897290708e+22
8    1.034685721591756e+24
9    1.266874815617544e+26
Name: col1 , dtype: float64
```

And 2nd column is

```
col2
>>> 0    4.366546513962408e+10
1    1.652022839203982e+13
2    7.379755212750794e+14
3    3.581032068558979e+16
4    1.929046707578994e+18
5    1.179372536567603e+20
6    8.359631557019926e+21
7    7.012307736342528e+23
8    7.078764509914335e+25
9    8.667277701968806e+27
Name: call2, dtype: float64
```

Now when I divide both element-wise, as mentioned in a lot of answers, we just have to divide them like this.

```
df['col1'] / df['col2']
```

But the result is a constant

```
>>> 0    0.014616755793226
1    0.014616755793226
2    0.014616755793226
3    0.014616755793226
4    0.014616755793226
5    0.014616755793226
6    0.014616755793226
7    0.014616755793226
8    0.014616755793226
9    0.014616755793226
dtype: float64
```

Which should not happen in the element wise division.

If I do it via a loop with manually entering values, it is correct.

```
l1 = [6.382474405435247e+08,  2.414721440547710e+11, 1.078680797585678e+13, 5.234307123383891e+14]
l2 = [1.652022839203982e+13, 7.379755212750794e+14, 3.581032068558979e+16, 1.929046707578994e+18]

for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    print(i, j)
    print(i / j)
```

Or If I create a new dataframe from these values then

```
s = pd.DataFrame({"l1":l1, "l2":l2})
s['l1'] / s['l2'] # correct
>>>0    0.000038634298836
1    0.000327208880367
2    0.000301220647270
3    0.000271341647811
```

i even converted both to Numpy and still not working.

```
print(df['col1'].to_numpy() / df['col2'].to_numpy())
>>>
[0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676
 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676]
```

Answer (score 3):

Reason is both Series has different indices, so if divide it are align each other -  `index=1` from first Series match with `index=1` from another Series.

For avoid it convert second Series to numpy array, only necessary same length of both Series:

```
df1['col1'] / df2['col2'].to_numpy()
```

Testing: Values are shifted

```
print (df['col2'].head(4).tolist())
[43665465139.62408, 16520228392039.82, 737975521275079.4, 3.581032068558979e+16]

print (l2)
[16520228392039.82, 737975521275079.4, 3.581032068558979e+16, 1.929046707578994e+18]
```

So for same ouput need:

```
print (df['col1'] / df['col2'].shift(-1))
0    0.000039
1    0.000327
2    0.000301
3    0.000271
4    0.000239
5    0.000206
6    0.000174
7    0.000145
8    0.000119
9         NaN
dtype: float64
```

With remove last value `NaN`:

```
print ((df['col1'] / df['col2'].shift(-1)).iloc[:-1])
0    0.000039
1    0.000327
2    0.000301
3    0.000271
4    0.000239
5    0.000206
6    0.000174
7    0.000145
8    0.000119
dtype: float64


l1 = [6.382474405435247e+08,  2.414721440547710e+11, 1.078680797585678e+13, 5.234307123383891e+14]
l2 = [1.652022839203982e+13, 7.379755212750794e+14, 3.581032068558979e+16, 1.929046707578994e+18]


for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    # print(i, j)
    print(i / j)
3.8634298836392646e-05
0.0003272088803671343
0.0003012206472699205
0.0002713416478107515
```

Comment: Not working, I even converted both to numpy and getting same constant answer. `
[0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676
 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676 0.01461676]`

Comment: @AhmadAnis - So it means `s = pd.DataFrame({"l1":df['col1'].tolist(), "l2":df['col2'].tolist()})
s['l1'] / s['l2'] #` working well?

Comment: Not if I create them from the series elements, but If I copy the elements separately from the series to make a new list, then it works well.

Comment: @AhmadAnis - hmm, I do it in comment above, your code is different?

Comment: You are creating it with `{"l1": df['col1'].tolist()` and I copy the value from the printed `df['col1']` as you can see in the question, l1 has manual values where I used the loop. If I do it as you have done, i still get the constant number.

Comment: If I do this, still get this same answer. `arr1 = "6.38247441e+08 2.41472144e+11 1.07868080e+13 5.23430712e+14 2.81964046e+16 1.72386004e+18 1.22190693e+20 1.02497190e+22 1.03468572e+24 1.26687482e+26".split()
arr2 = "4.36654651e+10 1.65202284e+13 7.37975521e+14 3.58103207e+16 1.92904671e+18 1.17937254e+20 8.35963156e+21 7.01230774e+23 7.07876451e+25 8.66727770e+27".split()

np.array(arr1, dtype='float32') / np.array(arr2, dtype='float32')`

Comment: It is working as you expect with `zip` since `zip` only pairs up to the length of the shortest iterable, i.e. it is removing the last value in your list. They are of different lengths as @jezrael has already said. 
Just make them the same length and the simple division will work as expected.

Comment: I missed the 0th index while copying. Edited the question. They are of the same length.

Comment: Also, I have set this option `pd.set_option("display.precision", 15)`, is it because of this?

Comment: How were these numbers generated? Pandas is behaving as expected, it's just that this _is_ the result. I think you may have offset accidentally.

Comment: Try `df['col1'] / df['col2'].shift(-1)` on your dataframe.

Comment: with shift(-1) I am getting last value as nan, and rest are different. Values were generated using a computation.

Comment: Yes you will get `nan` because the values are shifted back one row. I was suggesting that you have entered your values out of sync, as indicated by the sample you used in your loop.

Comment: @AhmadAnis - tested and difference is shifted values, added to answer.

Comment: I have just divided `col1` by `col2` on LibreOffice Calc (a spreadsheet), getting the exact same result obtained by the OP. However, if I do the same calculations on Excel, I get the following result: `1,45995423340961000E-02
1,46060606060606000E-02
1,46341463414634000E-02
1,46089385474860000E-02
1,46113989637306000E-02
1,45762711864407000E-02
1,45933014354067000E-02
1,45506419400856000E-02
1,45480225988701000E-02
1,46482122260669000E-02`. Maybe some overflow is the culprit?

Comment: @PaulS if divide `l1, l2` it is different division like val1, val2, so different output is expected.